# Use upstream servers based on request method with NGINX

Tags: nginx, proxy

i'm using nginx's upstream directive to do some load balancing. But i want to handle the POST requests and the requests for /upload directory by my main server.

how can i tell nginx "dont proxy pass if the request method is POST or the url contains /admin or /upload"?

my current upstreams looks like this:

```
upstream appcluster {
                ip_hash;
                server 10.200.0.194:9000; 
       }

        upstream admincluster {
                ip_hash;
                server unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;

        }
```

and my `sites-enabled/default`

```
location ~ \.php(.*)$ {
                try_files $uri =404;

                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini


                #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                #fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;

                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV production;

                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass appcluster;


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add something like this in front of the other location block:

```
location /upload {
  break;
}

location /admin {
  break;
}

if ($request_method = POST ) {
  break;
}
```

Update:

> nginx first searches for the most specific location given by literal
>   strings regardless of the listed order. In the configuration above the
>   only literal location is “/” and since it matches any request it will
>   be used as a last resort. Then nginx checks locations given by regular
>   expression in the order listed in the configuration file. The first
>   matching expression stops the search and nginx will use this location.
>   If no regular expression matches a request, then nginx uses the most
>   specific literal location found earlier.

So, the /upload and /admin location blocks are literals and are processed after the regex you're using for the proxy.

Try "location ~ ^/admin" and so on.

Comment: id does not work. i think i have to wrap the fastcgi_pass part in if block. but i dont know how to do it for locations. i can do it for request method.

Comment: Updated with more info.